# SpreadsheetApp.getActive()

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[image]

I have started on a journey of building an app (I'm not an IT professional) and I received some support with connecting my app with Google sheets.

Whilst all this works, I am seeking some guidance on an edit if this is possible. Currently the app will pull data from Google Sheets to the device. As you can see below in the code this is based on data in sheets rather than in ranges. Is it possible to change this so that I could store all the look up data in one sheet and in ranges, I have more to add and I may well end up with many sheets containing minimal data within.

```
if ( e.parameter.func == "static" ) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shFlr = ss.getSheetByName("Floors").getDataRange().getValues();
  var shRm = ss.getSheetByName("Rooms").getDataRange().getValues();
  var shItm = ss.getSheetByName("Items").getDataRange().getValues();
  var shCnd = ss.getSheetByName("Condition").getDataRange().getValues();
  var shBldg = ss.getSheetByName("Buildings").getDataRange().getValues();
  var shUOM = ss.getSheetByName("UOM").getDataRange().getValues();//Projects Added
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"UOM":shUOM,"Buildings":shBldg,"Floors":shFlr,"Rooms":shRm,"Items":shItm,"Condition":shCnd,})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
```

If anyone can describe how I could edit this I would be most grateful.

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are asking.  Your data is stored in ranges within sheets.

Comment: Hi Cooper, 

Each List (Floor, Room, Item) is listed on a separate sheet and I would like this all listed on one sheet (Perhaps called "Project").  I can do this but I need some guidance on the script part. 

My plan is something like this:

Sheet name = Project
Floor is in A1:A20
Room is in B1:20
Item is in C1:20

Many Thanks

Comment: How is the data entered?

Comment: Manually typed in the sheet.  These are lookup values for an app only.

Comment: Can provide an image of the current sheets and the expected final sheet?

Comment: I have some pictures but i don't have an option to upload the file??

Comment: In the question edit screen theirs an insert image control.  Read the edit help.

Comment: I don't sufficient rep load three images... this is painful

Comment: Put it all in one image.  Do you have an image editor?

Comment: Unfortunately not, I cant even load a single image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function doGet(e) {

  if ( e.parameter.func == "static" ) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("ProjectSetUp");
    var rgProj = sh.getRange("A3:A3").getValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function myfunction() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const shts=["Floors","Rooms","Items","Condtion","Buildings","UOM"];//These are the names of the individual sheets and there order determine the header location for each individual sheet.
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Combined');//I named the sheet Combined you can name it whatever you wish
  if(!sh) {var sh=ss.insertSheet('Combined');}//This creates the sheet if it's not already there
  sh.clear();//this clears the combined sheet
  sh.appendRow(shts);//This puts the header titles on the combined sheet
  shts.forEach(function(name,i){
    var s=ss.getSheetByName(name);//This gets the individual sheets
    var v=s.getRange(1,1,s.getLastRow(),1).getValues();//this gets each sheets one column of data
    sh.getRange(2,i+1,v.length,1).setValues(v);//this puts the data into each column of the combined sheet under that sheets name
  });
}
```

I haven't debugged this at all. So you will probably have to debug it.  I know your hoping that it works...so am I.

Comment: Thanks Cooper,

Getting the data onto one sheet is not an issue as these are very small lists and I can c&p these without and issue.  These lists are master data and are pick lists in an app. 
I am trying to edit my script so that instead of the pulling data based on tab/sheet it must come from a singular sheet where i have all this data in one tab/sheet.  The script below is based on data in sheets of various names.

Comment: ``if ( e.parameter.func == "static" ) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var shFlr = ss.getSheetByName("Floors").getDataRange().getValues(); // Sheet name should be ProjectSetUp and getting the data from a range
  var shRm = ss.getSheetByName("Rooms").getDataRange().getValues(); // Sheet name should be ProjectSetUp and getting the data from a range``

Comment: I have tried someting like this, but it errored? Not sure if I hashed up the JSON.Stringify element?

Comment: ``function doGet(e) {

if ( e.parameter.func == "static" ) {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName(ProjectSetUp) //This is a sheet name will all my lookup data.
  
  var rgBldg = activeSheet.getRange("C2:C59").getValues(); 
  var rgFlr = activeSheet.getRange("D2:D59").getValues(); 
  var rgRm = activeSheet.getRange("E2:D125").getValues();
  return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify({"C2:C59":rgBldg,"D2:D59":rgFlr,"E2:D125":rgRm})).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.JSON);
}``

Comment: Hi @Garth! I read your question and your comments. Based on your last commnet, could you please check if the variable `ProjectSetUp` is declared? If that doesn't help, please share the error that gets returned in that code so I can further help you.

Comment: Hi @Jacques-Guzel Heron,

Thanks for the message and offer of support, I now have a solution and here is the high level detail.

`function doGet(e) {
  
 if ( e.parameter.func == "static" ) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var sh = ss.getSheetByName("ProjectSetUp"); //Sheet Tab Name
    var rgProj = sh.getRange("A3:A3").getValues(); // Range`